# 14.04 Install disk not booting properly

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation, live-usb

Whether I use a USB or a DVD, the install program goes directly to an Ubuntu desktop with no mouse. So I added another mouse, but there are no programs, save for Accessibility, Network information, and the log off/exit dropdown.
My ultimate goal is to create an Ubuntu OS on a stick, but if I can't get the DVD to boot properly, I'm out of luck. At one point, on another computer, or maybe it was still within Windows(7) I forget, I got the install menu off the USB, but it won't allow me to inistall to another USB.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

See this official [USB Bootable disk creation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) document from Ubuntu. There is an option to select which operating system you are using as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad iso. Download a new iso to your Windows machine and selsct burn to disk. If you have ubuntu installed and it's sending you to the desktop change your boot order to 1 being the cdrom. When your BIOS screen appares press pause / break to pause the boot. Read the screen to see which key takes you to boot options. If your looking for a Live USB, you can also create a Live USB from an iso file in your Windows machine using a program called Unetbootin you can download from sourceforge. Also availible in software center. If you want an actual installed Linux on a USB instead of a HDD or SSD. Put in your Live DVD and select try Ubuntu. When you get to the Ubuntu desktop there should be an icon that says Install Ubuntu. Install your USB and then click the install icon. When you get to the install screen go to do something else and select the USB. Remember your filesystem is ext4 and your mount point is root ( / ) and leave 4gb in your partition. Then in that 4gb create a partition and select ( linux swap ). Then proceed with your install. Ubuntu on USB runs a little slower then from a drive. TTFN, toachGmon